# How do I use Nik with Creative Cloud?

Tags: plugin

So how do I use the new free nik with cc? Do I edit in cc(PS/LR etc) then move a copy into nik or will it open in PS etc? I have downloaded the program but have not installed it yet because I am funny in that I like to know what to do with anything first. Any help would be much appreciated.
j

Answer (score 1):

It's a plugin. Try the help files or documentation from Nik if you want to know how to use it([here](https://support.google.com/nikcollection/answer/3000959?hl=en&ref_topic=3000839)). If want to see the install in action see [here](https://support.google.com/nikcollection/answer/3000910?hl=en&ref_topic=3000839) or check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vEvOA6a4Gf0

Answer (score 0):

When you install the Nik collection, there will be a component where you select which program you have (PS, Lightroom, Elements, etc.)

The collection will be accessible from within the program. I use Elements and access it in the "Filters" menu.